# How to Update Column From Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to move data from ResultingStrings to ContourTemp. I got my sql query set:

```
   SELECT  
       (
       SELECT
          JSON_QUERY('{"Ksize":9,"Treshold1":50,"Treshold2":100,"Size1":100,"Size2":250}') as CalculationParameters,
          'CalculateWithCSharp' as CalculationProvider,
          (SELECT X1, Y1, X2, Y2 FROM SimpleLines WHERE ContourId = dc.ContourId FOR JSON AUTO) AS SimpleLines
       FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
       ) AS ResultingStrings,
       ContourId,
       ContourTemp
    FROM DbContours dc INNER JOIN [dbo].Measurements
    ON dc.ContourId = [dbo].Measurements.MeasurementId
```

This query returns:
[image]

but I don't know how to update ContourTemp Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update DbContours
set    
       ContourTemp = (
       SELECT
          JSON_QUERY('{"Ksize":9,"Treshold1":50,"Treshold2":100,"Size1":100,"Size2":250}') as CalculationParameters,
          'CalculateWithCSharp' as CalculationProvider,
          (SELECT X1, Y1, X2, Y2 FROM SimpleLines WHERE ContourId = dc.ContourId FOR JSON AUTO) AS SimpleLines
       FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
       ) 
     
       
    FROM DbContours dc INNER JOIN [dbo].Measurements
    ON dc.ContourId = [dbo].Measurements.MeasurementId
```